# Can't convert java.util.List to java.lang.Iterable of template interface

Tags: java, type-conversion

I'm having an issue using a list of objects implementing an interface as an iterable of that interface.

My class definitions are like this:

```java
class BaseObject implements AInterface<OtherObject> {...}

class Foo extends BaseObject{...}

interface BInterface{
void doSomething(AInterface<OtherObject> a);
void doSomethingToIterable(Iterable<AInterface<OtherObject>> a);
}
```

The code that won't compile is

```java
private BInterface bInterface;
...

public void baa(List<Foo> list){
   bInterface.doSomethingToIterable(list);//This is the line that gives a compilation error
   ...
}
```

The compilation error I'm getting from maven is

```
incompatible types: java.util.List<my.package.Foo> cannot be converted to java.lang.Iterable<my.other.package.AInterface<my.third.package.OtherObject>>
```

I can invoke `doSomething` to each element in the List. In fact, I can do this by inlining the implementation of `doSomethingToIterable`.

Running `java -version` in terminal produces the output

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252_b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.8.0_252_b09)
```

My understanding is that since `List` extends `Collection` which extends `Iterable`, and `Foo` extends `BaseObject` that implements `AInterface`, these two types should be compatible. It seems my understanding is wrong.

Why am I getting the above error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Try  `void doSomethingToIterable(Iterable<? extends AInterface<OtherObject>> a)`. Note  that `List<Subclass>` is *not* an instance of `List<Superclass>`

Comment: @Bohemian that worked. Can you make that into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<Subclass>` is not an instance of `List<Superclass>`.

Try:

```
void doSomethingToIterable(Iterable<? extends AInterface<OtherObject>> a)
```